# How to resend failed xmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

in my app I am trying to

1. Handle failed xmlHttpRequest
2. Authenticate
3. Resend failed xmlHttpRequest

I know how to catch error specialy for failed authorization with code 401:
I have special case for this type of error.

In this scenario I just want to catch it and resend.

```
 xhr.onloadend = function () {

       switch (xhr.status) {
                     .
                     .
                     .
                case 401:
                 console.log(xhr);
                 console.log("ERROR INVALID TOKEN");
                 xhr.send(); //this gives error about missing attributes
                break;
         }
  }
```

I tried search online but without result.

Comment: Instead of callinfg `xhr.send`, you should wrap all the code of your request in a `function` and calling it in case of error in the request.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ that is good idea but the problem is I have many requests and this error handler is for all requests. Do you have an advice for this? thx

Comment: Again, wrap the entire request code in a function. Add a parameter that contains details about the request. Then use that to re-run the function. You might also want to look into `fetch()` instead of manually using `XmlHttpRequest`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of callinfg xhr.send, you should wrap all the code of your request in a function and calling it in case of error in the request. Like below

```
function ErrorListener() {
  makeHTTPRequest();
}

function makeHTTPRequest(){
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("error", ErrorListener);
oReq.open("GET", "http://www.example.org/example.txt");
oReq.send();
}
```

Comment: That approach will end up in a loop if the error isn't resolved, effectively DDoSing the website.